# Connect to Sharepoint site using specific username/Password through WinForm App

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

Hay,
I'm working on a windows form application (C#) that connects to a sharepoint site and read data from it (lists),

**the question is:**
how can I connect to the site using specific username/Password, and not using the current windowsUser or domain user.

Please advice

**Edit**: P.S.: working on SP 2007

**My code:**

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite sourceSite = new SPSite(txtBoxSP.Text))
            {
                SPWeb sourceWeb = sourceSite.RootWeb;
                SPUserCollection usrs = sourceWeb.AllUsers;

                SPListCollection col = sourceWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.GenericList);

                foreach (SPList list in col)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("My Name: {0}, Type: {1}, Length: {2}",
                        list.Title, list.GetType().ToString(), list.ItemCount.ToString()));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
var cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
    new Uri(sourceSite.Url), 
    "NTLM", 
    new NetworkCredential("user", "password"));
sourceSite.Credentials = cc;
```

Of course hard-coding a password like this is not very secure. You might ask the user about it. [NetworkCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?view=net-6.0) has another [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.-ctor?view=net-6.0) taking a secure string for this purpose.

---

UPDATE:

I didn't notice you wre using the SharePoint object model. Initially I thought you were generating a proxy from the WSDL. [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tejasr/ways-to-pass-security-credentials-to-web-service-call) of how to achieve this.

Comment: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite' does not contain a definition for 'Credentials' and no extension method 'Credentials' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ! please advice..

Comment: On Update: what is the 'web' object?, I guess the example you provided talking about webPart development not winApp, right?

Comment: In the example (number `[3]`) they use an `SPUserToken` which is passed to the constructor of `SPSite`.

Comment: There are missing points!, what is 'web' object he uses in the example? is it a 'SPWeb', and what is the 'impUser' object? I guess uses he currentContext which is only found in the sharepoint webPart host environment, or am I missing something?.

Comment: It's an `SPWeb` instance. Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx

Comment: It turns out that sharePoint object model not allowed to connect to sharepoint server remotely, it must (the application) runs on the server machine, so im on using webServices now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can help you

From **MSDN** Find given lines in this page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829215.aspx I think this article will show you a way. Tell me if you cant find these lines :)

```
Connection Strings

There may be situations where you need to display data from databases or REST and SOAP services. Accessing data from these data sources requires either connection strings or at least the URL and endpoints of the services to be stored somewhere. Web.config files are an obvious choice but using Web.config files in SharePoint has some caveats. 
The first differentiation we have to make is whether or not we are developing a sandboxed solution. Let’s look at the farm solution first. Farm solutions have access to the file system. Because every site collection is hosted in a web application and every web application has a Web.config file, the Web.config file associated with your farm solution is one place you can store connection strings or other data. The method for doing this is similar to how it is done in ASP.NET development.
```